# Struggling to understand the effects of access modifiers and the keyword "static"

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I'm pretty new to Java. I've just written a small example to observe the effects of access modifiers. Maybe the code does not make much sense since I'm just testing things out.

The first code snippet looks like this:

```java
class Tet {
    static double a;
    double b;
    public Tet(double a, double b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    
    public void get(){
        a=5;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tet tet1 = new Tet(2, 5);
        Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);
        System.out.println(tet1.a);
        a=4;
        System.out.println(tet1.a);
        tet1.get();
        System.out.println(tet1.a);
        System.out.println(a);
        
    }
}
```

After this, I made some changes to the code and compiled it again:

```java
class Tet {
    static double a;
    double b;
    public Tet(double a, double b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    
    public static void get(){
        a=5;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tet tet1 = new Tet(2, 5);
        Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);
        System.out.println(a);
        get();
        System.out.println(tet1.a);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(tet2.a);
        
    }
}
```

After it runs, the cmd looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHHxa.png)

I really don't know where is number 4 coming from.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've understood it now. If only I can mark everyone's as "resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All Java's variables must be known at compile time unlike Python, in either way:

   1. declare local variable (in this case, declare `int a` in your `main`)
   2. qualify variable (in this case, change to `Tet.a`)
   3. (`import` variable, but it's a bit longer and redundant this case)
2. You're touching `static` area - an special storage. `static` variables are **shared** across all class instances. So:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Tet tet1 = new Tet(2, 5); // set Tet's `a` to 2
    // update `a` to 4.
    // `a` is shared across `tet1` and `tet2`!
    Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);
    // Watch out, `Tet`'s `a` is shared! It'll output 4
    System.out.println(tet1.a); 
    System.out.println(tet1.a);
    tet1.get(); // `get`, but updates `a` to 5
    System.out.println(tet1.a); // This will be 5 as well
}
```

---

If this answer resolves your question, consider mark this as "resolved" :)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one instance of static fields for each class.

In this case there is one instance of `a`. So when you create the `tet2` instance `Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);`, you just set its value to 4.

Comment: Simple but effective, thank you man

Answer (score 2):

I can see how these things can be confusing, so no need to apologise.

Firstly, with static members, you shouldn't be using the `this` keyword as a static member belongs to a class itself and not an instance, i.e. objects of that class. Or put in a [clearer way](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static):

> In the Java programming language, the keyword static means that the
> particular member belongs to a type itself, rather than to an instance
> of that type.
>
> This means we'll create only one instance of that static member that
> is shared across all instances of the class.

So change your constructor:

```
public Tet(double a, double b){
    Tet.a =a;
    this.b=b;
}
```

You can even change the client code.

Furthermore, I would also recommend you watch this high-level video on Java memory management: https://youtu.be/4yKxJjYXZ0A or read [this article by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html).

Access modifiers are more of a general concept in Java and aren't pertinent to a discussion around static members. Basically, it pertains to the visibility of a member, e.g. classes, variables, etc. Please read this [article](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/access-modifiers) on the matter.

To answer your question, the "number 4" comes from `Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);` because through the constructor, you're still updating the *value* of the static variable despite not creating a new object of it; it'll still have the same *memory address*, but its *value* can change as they aren't the same. And you change it again to "5" by invoking the `get();` method.

I hope this clarifies a few things, and let me know if I've made any mistakes in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

to understand the meaning of keyword called `static` please refer to [this small tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/) to understand the meaning of static. so when you coded the following 2 lines :

```
    Tet tet1 = new Tet(2, 5);
    Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);
```

this made 2 instances of the class called **Tet** but the variable called **a** is static means it's shared among the 2 instances.

so when you write `Tet tet1 = new Tet(2, 5);` it made this diagram as a brief representation :

[image]

but then when wrote `Tet tet2 = new Tet(4, 5);` the following diagram happened and **a** was updated with the new value as it's shared :

[image]

so both instances of **Tet** have that variable called **a** which is shared meaning if you updated **a** using any of the 2 instance , it's updated in the second instance also.

also in **C** language, making the variable `static` means that it's only one instance and also private to the file meaning you can't extern that variable to any other file